# Why QGIS was detected as threat and therefore cannot be opened?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

QGIS is always detected as a threat. Therefore, due to some files in quarantine, the application cannot be opened.

I have already reinstalled QGIS. Do I need to unquarantine all the files or is there another solution? What could be the reason that QGIS is considered a threat.

Comment: I suppose you are on Windows, is not it? Which QGIS version is that?

Comment: did you download QGIS from the official QGIS website ?

Comment: What exactly files were detected as s threat? Have you downloaded .dll files from third-party websites? (.dll files can be dangerous, you should not install them from suspicious websites, for example qgis_app.dll from dll-files.com)

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32247

Comment: Thank you, it has now worked after trying again. Yes, on Windows with version 3.16 downloaded from the official QGIS website.

Comment: I see your problem is solved, but could you state what version of Windows and antivirus you are using?